# Do I need a pivot query for this example or is it simpler than that?

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table that records the success/failure of a particular job run for each item it processes.

Some test data and a little of my testing is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData
(
ItemType  VARCHAR(10),
Task      VARCHAR(10),
Status    INT,
BatchId   INT)

INSERT INTO #TestData
SELECT 'A', 'D', 1, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'D', 1, 5
UNION ALL         
SELECT 'A', 'D', 2, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'U', 1, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'U', 2, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 1, 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', 'D', 1, 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', 'D', 2, 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', 'U', 1, 6

SELECT * FROM #TestData

SELECT BatchId, 
       ItemType, 
       Task,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 1 THEN [status] ELSE 0 END) as [Success], 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 2 THEN [status] ELSE 0 END) AS [Failed]
FROM #TestData
GROUP BY BatchId, ItemType, Task
ORDER BY BatchId

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

What I would like to see here is a distinct row for each combination of BatchId, ItemType and Task and then an alongside that a count of the Success and Failures.

So for the data posted above, I'd expect to see;

```
Batch  ItemType Task  Success  Failed
  5       A      D      2        1
  5       A      U      1        1
  6       B      D      2        1
  6       B      U      1        0
```

Can I do this without the need for a pivot table? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it will work for you:

```
SELECT BatchId, 
       ItemType, 
       Task
       ,sum(CASE WHEN [status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Success]
       ,sum(CASE WHEN [status] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Failed]
FROM #TestData
GROUP BY BatchId, ItemType, Task
ORDER BY BatchId
```

Comment: Alison, this looks GREAT. I'll do a bit more testing with some real data. I also need to get a better understanding of a CASE statement inside a SUM within a SELECT.

Comment: Further testing shows that this works a treat. Thanks heaps Alison.